# As3 iPad softkeyboard keycode listen

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I would like to listen for user to Click the 'DONE' button to do my form submission. I am using Textfiled not StageText. Is there a way you can listen to user Click on it.

Cheers
Bill

Comment: If you listen for key events, do you get a key code when pressing the Done button?

Comment: @walkietokyo i am testing it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done couple testing, looks like keycodeEvent dose works. 'Done' is equal as 'Enter'. the code is '13'

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for FlexEvent.ENTER on the TextInput - it gets fired when user closes soft keyboard by clicking 'done'

To listen for soft keyboard closing in general, add SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_DEACTIVATE listener to TextInput

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS82181550ec4a666a39bafe0312d9a274c00-8000.html#WS19f279b149e7481c-66e67e6c13313699023-8000 for full info.